# Java replace ' " 'character with ' \" '

Tags: java, string

I am trying to update text into a MySql Database. 
The text contains "  marks in it.
As example string could be Hello "world" 
now when i write insert command its sumthing like

insert into mytable ('mystring') values("Hello "world"");

I am using java to execute a command like this. Obviously this gives an error due to the double quotes in the world string. I tried replacing it with java 
`givenString.replaceAll("\"", "\\"");`
`givenString.replace(Pattern.quote("\""), "\\"");`

But nothing works . Any help is greatly appreciated !

Comment: Sounds like a job for parameter binding and prepared statements.

Comment: thanks lemme try it out.

Comment: Note, you might want to worry what happens if someone a bit malicious puts a `\` in the text. Or control characters, or whatever. Best stick with `PreparedStatement`. And that's general to avoid injection attacks when producing any text format.

Comment: prepared statment to rescue. Thanks a ton for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Double escape the `\` like so:

```
givenString.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");
```

As stated by Ted Hopp in comments, for inserting data into a table you should user prepared statements using parameters, and set them according to the API you are using. For example if you are using JDBC you may use the `setString` method of your `Statement` object.

```
String str = "Hello \"world";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(
      "insert into mytable('column') values(?)");
stmt.setString(1, str);
```

About your first comment:

In Java Strings are immutable, so `replaceAll` returns a new instance whose contents is the string with the required replacements. So what you want is to assign again the result to the previous variable, like so:

```
public String getSqlLikeString(String givenString) {
   System.out.println(givenString); 
   givenString = givenString.replaceAll("\"", "\\\""); 
   System.out.println(givenString); 
   return givenString;
}

// or just
public String getSqlLikeString(String givenString) {
   return givenString.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");
}
```

Comment: i already did that but some how its not working . this is my code `public String GetSqlLikeString(String givenString){
        System.out.println(givenString);
        givenString.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");            
        System.out.println(givenString);
        return givenString;
    }
    ` I believe java compiler is not able to look up for it or what .

Comment: yes you are right about the new instance. Turns out `givenstring = givenString.replaceall("\"","ab")` works fine by replacing the " with the string ab. But `givenString = givenString.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");` does not replace all " with \"

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    String s = "hello \"world\"";
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(s.replace("\"", "\\\""));
```

Comment: i am getting a string from web basically an rss feed. i intend to update that to my database thats why need to add the escape characters.